# Bootstrap-table extension import in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, bootstrap-table, es6-modules

I'd like to load/import and use the Bootstrap-table extensions but no luck yet...

The basic module load is fine:

I've added with yarn to the `package.json` and it sits there like this:

```
"bootstrap-table": "^1.11.2",
```

In the javascript file I import it:

```
import BootstrapTable from "bootstrap-table";
```

And the usage is fine as well:

```
$.extend($.fn.bootstrapTable.defaults, {
  filterControl: true,
  showMultiSort: true
});

$('.element').bootstrapTable();
```

But (obviously) it doesn't pick the custom options up. How should I load the extensions from the `node_modules/bootstrap-table/src/extensions` directory?

in ES5 I've had to load those js files one by one, after the `bootstrap-table.js`. But how does it work in ES6?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to use something like Webpack to do imports.

Comment: @CraigvanTonder I need this bootstrap-table only in certain js files and not in globally.

Comment: If you aren't using a bundler then you will need to add them like you have previously, ES5 would have been `var  BootstrapTable = require('bootstrap-table')` I'm guessing that isn't what you were doing because you would be using a bundler for that as well.

Comment: @craig_h I'm using bundler, but the import is working fine for the bootstrap-table itself. My question is that how I can use the extensions, like the filter-control? How should I import that as well? Because if I import the bootstrap-table, that doesn't import the extension(s) what I want to use with it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use named `imports` the package would need to use named `exports`, I've just taken a look at that package and it doesn't, so you can't import a single module member with the ES6 syntax:

```
import {Module} from 'my-package';
```

so you will have to reference the file directly in your `node_modules` folder:

```
import FilterControl from '/node_modules/bootstrap-table/dist/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js';
```

It might be worth raising an issue asking the package publisher to add the [named exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export), which is essentially one file entry point that exports everything for you.